# Bash - Have I put the quotations in the right place?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a bit confused about stripping out the filename of a URL using bash in a function. This is what I have written, but I'm new to this, and cant figure out if I have done it right.

```
function file_download()
{
    filename={$1##*/}
    tar xzf $filename

}

file_download "http://www.url.com/test.zip"
```

Should I be putting quotations around the "$1"?

Comment: In fact, you made several mistakes: argument access should be "${1##*/}" (you got right the stripping of the front part!). You use a global variable in the function ($filename). You didn't quote the variable when accessing it (should be "$filename"), same for argument access. And you don't need this $filename variable at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` should be *outside* of the expression:

```
filename="${1##*/}"
```

This will give you `test.zip`, as expected. Otherwise, you'll get `{http://www.url.com/test.zip##*/}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `basename` for this:

```
filename="$(basename "$1")"
```

That way, you don't end up with a meaningless empty string if you try to download `http://www.example.com/`.